# Hibernate OneToMany and related deletion constraints

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

I have two related classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {

@Expose
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
...
@Expose
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<WorkPackage> workPackages;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "work_packages")
public class WorkPackage {

@Expose
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Expose(serialize = false)
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
private Project project;
}
```

Now the issue:
i have Project object which contains one or more WorkPackage objects stored in DB.
When i delete the project there is no any violation. Project is deleted, but related WPs are still in DB and referring to not existing (after deletion) project. This isn't behavior i expect. I need a violation when i try to delete project that contains at least one WP.

Apparently I can do it in DB directly but i wonder if there is a way to do it through Hibernate and Annotations?

Thanks!

**SOLUTION**

The problem was Hibernate created Tables with MyISAM engine, which doesn't allow to generate FK apparently.
So i just changed

```
property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"
```

to

```
property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect"
```

and it works ( now Hibernate uses InnoDB engine)

Comment: "Apparently I can do it in DB" you mean adding a foreign key i suppose?
the annotation@JoinColumn(name = "project_id") is specifically to map a foreign key but it need to be present in db to work. 
P.s. do you have hibernate.ddl-auto=validate in your properties? if not try to add it as it should tell your right away if there are inconsistencies between mapping and db

Comment: @Zeromus yes i meant foreign key. <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>. I don't know why "JoinColumn" didn't generate constraint in DB...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
@Expose
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
```

With `orphanRemoval=true` all child records of a parent record in a database will be deleted after the parent gets deleted.

Comment: actually the point is i don't need orphan removal, i want DB doesn't accept delete command.

Comment: I don't see anything particularly wrong with your code, it should generate a constraint as long as there is a foreign key in the other table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you added the Fk after some test run

The problem lies within the property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update`
as it won't modify existing table column definitions.

- It will only add a column that doesn't already exist.
- It will not modify or delete a column that is already present in db.

If you drop the table in db and try it again (if you are working on a test database obviously) you should find the foreign key correctly created.

Comment: may be you're right. i tried to drop tables, but i think not all of them. i'll try now to drop all. thanks for the hint!

Comment: doesn't work. i have another suggestion. i found out that right now hibernate uses MyISAM engine, and there is a notice that FK can be defined for certain storage engines... may be these don't include MyISAM. will try to change it to InnoDB